# Put text in center of button

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my text isnt in the vertical center of my button.

```css
button {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 20px;
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

I need to keep the padding and height as it is

Comment: simply remove the height.

Comment: I need to keep it that height

Answer (score 1):

then remove the top and bottom padding

```css
button {
    height: 35px;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this increase height and width as per requirement

```css
button {
    height: 50px;
    width:60
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the padding I have

Comment: then you need to not define height

Comment: I need the defined height and the padding. Is there not any other thing i can use

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

Add a line height of 0px.

Please see jsFiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have set the height to 35px and the padding to 20px all around the button. That will actually make the button 40px in height.

So the solution would be to remove the top and bottom paddings, and set the height to 40px.

```css
button {
   height: 40px;
   padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Hi
</button>
```

An alternate solution could also be to set the `line-height` to 0, but the above solution would be more sense, since the button is in fact 40 pixels in height and not 30.